# Select and Group Number range in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
    SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Vote BETWEEN 1 and 6 THEN '1-8'
        WHEN Vote BETWEEN 7 and 8 THEN '7-8'
        WHEN Vote BETWEEN 9 and 10 THEN '9-10'
    END AS Vote_range,
    COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM CaseRatingVote
    GROUP BY Vote_range
GO
```

How can i make this work in MSSQL i need a group on the different number ranges.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the exact same expression in the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Vote BETWEEN 1 and 6 THEN '1-8'
        WHEN Vote BETWEEN 7 and 8 THEN '7-8'
        WHEN Vote BETWEEN 9 and 10 THEN '9-10'
    END AS Vote_range,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM 
    CaseRatingVote
GROUP BY 
    CASE
        WHEN Vote BETWEEN 1 and 6 THEN '1-8'
        WHEN Vote BETWEEN 7 and 8 THEN '7-8'
        WHEN Vote BETWEEN 9 and 10 THEN '9-10'
    END
```

Or, as alternative, calculate your grouping column first (without grouping) and in a outer scope, group by that column. This approach is better for maintaining.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN Vote BETWEEN 1 and 6 THEN '1-8'
            WHEN Vote BETWEEN 7 and 8 THEN '7-8'
            WHEN Vote BETWEEN 9 and 10 THEN '9-10'
        END AS Vote_range
    FROM 
        CaseRatingVote
)
SELECT
    Vote_range,
    COUNT(1)
FROM
    CTE AS C
GROUP BY
    C.Vote_range
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Vote < 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [1-6],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Vote BETWEEN 7 AND 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [7-8],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Vote BETWEEN 9 AND 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [9-10],
        COUNT(*) AS count
 FROM CaseRatingVote
```

This was the easy way to do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to do this:

```
with a as (
    SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Vote BETWEEN 1 and 6 THEN '1-8'  --You may want to change this line!
        WHEN Vote BETWEEN 7 and 8 THEN '7-8'
        WHEN Vote BETWEEN 9 and 10 THEN '9-10'
    END AS Vote_range
    FROM CaseRatingVote
)
select  Vote_Range, count(*) as Row_Count
from    a
group by Vote_Range
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your query up in a derived table, `group by` its result:

```
select Vote_range, count(*) from
(
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN Vote BETWEEN 1 and 6 THEN '1-8'
    WHEN Vote BETWEEN 7 and 8 THEN '7-8'
    WHEN Vote BETWEEN 9 and 10 THEN '9-10'
END AS Vote_range
FROM CaseRatingVote
) dt
GROUP BY Vote_range
```